# Скрыть и показать элементы формы

Tags: javascript

У меня есть несколько списков select или input type = radio. Возможно ли по нажатии кнопки куда-нибудь (например в другой input type = radio или button) сделать так, что б в форме появлялся определённый список (а остальные были скрыты тем временем)? Причём желательно, что б они появлялись на одном и том же месте друг вместо друга. Скажу сразу, что о JS я имею только самое общее представление, но так сложилось, что надо реализовать это. Буду рад готовому решению, т.к. хочется сделать это без углубления в язык программирования. Но за ссылку на хороший материал по этому вопросу тоже буду благодарен.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это работа **за автора**.

Comment: К сожалению, без углубления в языки не получится сделать хорошее решение. Рекомендую Вам сначала воспользоваться google. Хоть какие-то намеки на решение у Вас есть уже? Или вы просто хотите готовое решение?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, плюсую, но считаю что нужно конкретизировать.

Comment: >"Хоть какие-то намеки на решение у Вас есть уже? Или вы просто хотите готовое решение?" Есть. Я могу сделать это с помощью фреймов и постоянного обращения к пхп скрипту. Но я хочу что б сразу все решилось в браузере.

Comment: @Wolfram, значит все сводится к _напишите код за меня_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хорошей практикой в этом случае будет Jquery

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option>Укажите вариант</option>
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
</select>
<div id="firts" style="display:none">
    ваши элементы при варианте 1
</div>
<div id="second" style="display:one">
    ваши элементы при варианте 2
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (window) {
        $('#myselect').on('change',function(){
            switch(this.value){
                case "1":
                    $('#first').show();
                    $('#second').hide();
                break;
                case "2":
                    $('#first').hide();
                    $('#second').show();
                break;
                default:
                    $('#first').hide();
                    $('#second').hide();
                break;
            }
        });
    })(window);
</script>
```